# not greedy and optional comma splits the whole string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:
`[Example] öäüß asdf 1234 (1aö) (not necessary),`

Explanation:

`[Example]`  optional, not needed

`öäüß asdf 1234` the most important part which I need. Every character, number, special character as well as German characters like `äÄöÖüÜß` can be found here.
A greedy selection might be the best solution to prevent characters like the German ones, right?

`(1aö)` optional and needed

`(not necessary)` optional, not needed. If it appears it could be `(not ...)` or `(unusual)`

`,` the comma can be optional, too. But is also not needed.

I use the following RegEx: `/(?:\[.*\]\s)?(?<name>.*?)(?:\s\([not|unusual].*?\))?\,/g`

The problems:

1. when I use the optional parameter `?` at the comma it splits the whole string into separate characters.
2. when I change the non greedy selection in the `name` group to a greedy one the optional comma is separated. But now the example string starting with `ö` is selected up to the end.
3. the string inside of the first standard brackets `()` can start with upper or lower case. At this moment I can only recognize upper case.

Here's my attempt at regex101 with a bunch of examples: https://regex101.com/r/Lx2anw/1

Sorry for the quite specific question, but I'm at the end with my knowledge ...

Does anyone have suggestions what I can do here?

Comment: Are you using a programming language here?

Comment: Yes. I`m using this in Javascript to match it out of a selected text.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? `A greedy selection might be the best solution to prevent characters like the German ones` you don't want German characters? Currently the group `name` always matches until the end of the string because all that follows in the pattern is optional, and I think you meant to use this right? `(?:not|unusual)`

Comment: As an aside `[not|unusual]` should be `(not|unusual)`

Comment: I really want to match german characters. That is why i wrote that a greedy selection might be the best option to not miss them. Atleast in the middle part `öäüß asdf 1234 (1aö)`

Comment: How about [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/3PH6F6/1) with use of negated classes.

Comment: @GePu Like this? https://regex101.com/r/ZMnnoh/1

Comment: @bobblebubble: It fails on the sentence `what Panda (not necessary),`

Comment: @Thefourthbird pretty good approach! But there's still matching a komma when there're no brackets.

Comment: @Luuk Thank you, indeed. I've not read about that before :) Maybe just [like this one](https://regex101.com/r/mt3DU9/1) or the pattern from the 4th bird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:\[.*?]\s)?(?<name>.*?)(?:\s\((?:not|unusual)[^()]*\))?,?\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BiYVPw/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\[.*?]\s)?` - an optional sequence of `[...]` and a whitespace
- `(?<name>.*?)` - Group "name": any zero or more chars as few as posible
- `(?:\s\((?:not|unusual)[^()]*\))?` - an optional sequence of a whitespace, `(`, `not` or `unusual`, and then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `,?` - an optional comma
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 6):

Your pattern matches the rest of the line in group 1 because all that follows in the pattern after group *name* is optional.

Note that you use a character class `[not|unusual]` but you should use a grouping if you want to match one of the alternatives like `(?:not|unusual)`

You might also match any character except parenthesis, or a comma that is at the end of the string.

Then match an optional part between parenthesis.

```
^(?:\[[^\][\n]*\]\s)?(?<name>(?:(?!,\s*$)[^\n()])*(?:\([^()\n]*\))?)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\[[^\][\n]*\]\s)?` Optionally match `[...]`
- `(?<name>` Group *name*

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!,\s*$)[^\n()]` If we are not looking at a trailing comma, match any character except `(` `)` or a newline
  - `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1 or more times to not match an empty line
  - `(?:\([^()\n]*\))?` Optionally match a part from `(...)`
- `)` Close group name

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CEn8zn/1)

If the first part between parenthesis should not start with the words *not* or *unusual* you can assert for it using a negative lookahead `(?!not\b|unusual\b)`

```
^(?:\[[^\][\n]*\]\s)?(?<name>(?:(?!,\s*$)[^\n()])+(?:\((?!not\b|unusual\b)[^()\n]*\))?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ENIkIE/1)

Answer (score 5):

It will work if you put every expression that you don't want to match as a single non-captured group.
Your expression will be like this:

```
/(?:\[.*\]\s)?(?<name>.+?)(?:\s\(not \w+\))?(?:\s\(unusual\))?,?$/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/a7Qtvw/1